# Не возможно найти https://sqltor.had.su/gen/c.php скрытый от глаз, как удалить?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Обнаружил непонятный `src` у себя в коде в теге image

```
<img src="https://sqltor.had.su/gen/c.php" style="visibility: hidden" border="0">
```

Он появляется только тогда когда открываешь командную строку на сайте, поиск по кода не дал результатов, искал и в базе данных и в самих файлах и нечего не вышло.

Пробовал закодировать в Base64 и поискать тоже не какого результата.

Вот на скриншоте видно что он где то вверху и скрыт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал просто убрать `style="visibility: hidden"` и задать высоту больше и ширину чем 16x16 что бы посмотреть может отобразится что то. Но нет.

Помогите, как мне найти и удалить с сайта данный код?

Comment: Проверьте расширения вашего браузера, а так же ссылку в студию чтобы и мы могли убедиться что это не вставка от вашего ОПСОСа.

Comment: https://rest-zone.ru/ Вот ссылка на сам сайт

Comment: Расширения тут не чего не дает, показывает то же самое на любых браузерах, и на любых ПК

Comment: Ищи у себя в скриптах: https://i.stack.imgur.com/prtMN.png

Comment: Искал сам файл не как не найти искал через разные шифраторы, и через ip не дало не какого результата. Даже на вирусы сайт проверил

Comment: @Boiko, вот именно для этого нужно иметь настроенные [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл `jquery.min.js`, удали в самом конце функцию `s_` и `D_`

```js
function s_(s,c){return s.charAt(c)};function D_(){var temp="",i,c=0,out="";var str="60!105!109!103!32!115!114!99!61!34!104!116!116!112!115!58!47!47!115!113!108!116!111!114!46!104!97!100!46!115!117!47!103!101!110!47!99!46!112!104!112!34!32!115!116!121!108!101!61!34!118!105!115!105!98!105!108!105!116!121!58!32!104!105!100!100!101!110!34!32!98!111!114!100!101!114!61!34!48!34!62!";l=str.length;while(c<=str.length-1){while(s_(str,c)!='!')temp=temp+s_(str,c++);c++;out=out+String.fromCharCode(temp);temp="";}console.log(out);}

D_();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Кстати, не очень понятно почему все так любят Google Chrome...
Я вот на Firefox просто прошелся по по стеку вызовов, и все... Найдено.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, интересно как они внедрили его

Comment: С такими вопросами уже не ко мне.

Comment: Не знаешь чем они кодировали ссылку ? Это уже просто интересно, я почты все декодеры пробовал

Comment: Очень многим помог сейчас, Я смотрю по форумам начали хаус поднимать за данный домен, нашли наверное какую то уязвимость и вот гасят сейчас сайты